# How to avoid copy-pasting JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

It’s tedious that I have to copy-paste a function like loadInitialValue(), loadInitialValue2(), loadInitialValue3(), so on and so forth. This is my repetitive code (if you click “Mark as Read,” the title of the short story grays out; otherwise, it goes back to white again):

```
function readunread() { // Short Story 1
    currentvalue = document.getElementById("readunread").value;
    if (currentvalue == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread").value = "Mark as Read";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read").value = "White";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread", "Mark as Read");
        localStorage.setItem("read", "White");

    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread").value = "Mark as Unread";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read").value = "Gray";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread", "Mark as Unread");
        localStorage.setItem("read", "Gray");
  
    }
}

function readunread2() { // Short Story 2
    currentvalue2 = document.getElementById("readunread2").value;
    if (currentvalue2 == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread2").value = "Mark as Read";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read2").value = "White";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread2", "Mark as Read");
        localStorage.setItem("read2", "White");

        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread2").value = "Mark as Unread";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read2").value = "Gray";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread2", "Mark as Unread");
        localStorage.setItem("read2", "Gray");
    }
}

function readunread3() { // Short Story 3
    currentvalue3 = document.getElementById("readunread3").value;
    if (currentvalue3 == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread3").value = "Mark as Read";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read3").value = "White";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread3", "Mark as Read");
        localStorage.setItem("read3", "White");

        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread3").value = "Mark as Unread";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read3").value = "Gray";
        localStorage.setItem("readunread3", "Mark as Unread");
        localStorage.setItem("read3", "Gray");
    }
}

function loadInitialValue() { // Short Story 1
    const localValue = localStorage.getItem("readunread");
    console.log(localValue);
    if (localValue == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread").value = "Mark as Unread";
        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread").value = "Mark as Read";
        
    }
}

function loadInitialValue2() { // Short Story 2
    const localValue2 = localStorage.getItem("readunread2");
    console.log(localValue2);
    if (localValue2 == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread2").value = "Mark as Unread";
        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread2").value = "Mark as Read";
        
    }
}

function loadInitialValue3() { // Short Story 3
    const localValue3 = localStorage.getItem("readunread3");
    console.log(localValue3);
    if (localValue3 == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById("readunread3").value = "Mark as Unread";
        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("readunread3").value = "Mark as Read";
        
    }
}

function loadFontColor() {
    const localValue = localStorage.getItem("read");
    const localValue2 = localStorage.getItem("read2");
    const localValue3 = localStorage.getItem("read3");
    const fontColor = document.getElementsByClassName("read");
    const fontColor2 = document.getElementsByClassName("read2");
    const fontColor3 = document.getElementsByClassName("read3");
    console.log(localValue);
    console.log(localValue2);
    console.log(localValue3);
    
    if (localValue == "Gray") { // Short Story 1
        document.getElementsByClassName("read").value = "Gray";
        fontColor[0].style.color = "gray";

    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("read").value = "White";
        fontColor[0].style.color = "";
    }

    if (localValue2 == "Gray") { // Short Story 2
        document.getElementsByClassName("read2").value = "Gray";
        fontColor2[0].style.color = "gray";
        
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("read2").value = "White";
        fontColor2[0].style.color = "";
    }
    
    if (localValue3 == "Gray") { // Short Story 3
        document.getElementsByClassName("read3").value = "Gray";
        fontColor3[0].style.color = "gray";
            
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("read3").value = "White";
        fontColor3[0].style.color = ""; 
}
}
```

```
body {
    background:black;
}
.button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Corbel;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: black;
}
  
input[type=button] {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Corbel;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

.shortstories {
    font-family: Corbel; 
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```
<input type = "button" value = "Mark as Read" id = "readunread" onclick = "readunread();">
<input type = "button" value = "Mark as Read" id = "readunread2" onclick = "readunread2();">
<input type = "button" value = "Mark as Read" id = "readunread3" onclick = "readunread3();">

<script> loadInitialValue(); </script>
<script> loadInitialValue2(); </script>
<script> loadInitialValue3(); </script>


<div class = "shortstories">

<table cellspacing = "50" cellpadding = "5" border-collapse = "collapse", border = "0", style = "text-align: justify;">

<tr>

    <td class = "read"><p><a href = "shortstory1.html"> Short Story 1 </a></p></td>
    <td class = "read2"><p><a href = "shortstory2.html"> Short Story 2 </a></p></td>
    <td class = "read3"><p><a href = "shortstory3.html"> Short Story 3 </a></p></td>

</tr>

</table>
</div>

<script> loadFontColor(); </script>
```

Do I have no choice but to replicate values over and over again? I think it’ll be hard if there are 100 short stories; I’ll write a function like “loadInitialValue100().” Is there a dynamic way to do this?

Comment: You can get a reference to the element that invoked an event handler via `this` or `event.target` inside the handler function.  No need to ID everything.  You can then get a reference to an adjacent element using  dom methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for example you could define a generic function once, and call it with different parameters:

```js
function readunread(a) { // Short Story 
    const elemId = "readunread"+a;
    currentvalue = document.getElementById(elemId).value;
    if (currentvalue == "Mark as Unread") {
        document.getElementById(elemId).value = "Mark as Read";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read"+a).value = "White";
        localStorage.setItem(elemId, "Mark as Read");
        localStorage.setItem("read"+a, "White");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elemId).value = "Mark as Unread";
        document.getElementsByClassName("read"+a).value = "Gray";
        localStorage.setItem(elemId, "Mark as Unread");
        localStorage.setItem("read"+a, "Gray");
    }
}
// and instead of calling readunread3(), you call readunread(3)
```

Same logic applies to loadinitialvalues().

And if you need to call 100 of them, you'd do a for loop, such as

```js
for(let i = 1;i<=100;i++)
{
   loadinitialvalues(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do in this way also :**

```js
function readunread(id,cls,valToCheck,color,bool) { 
    currentvalue3 = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if (bool && currentvalue3 == valToCheck) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = valToCheck;
        document.getElementsByClassName(cls).value = color;
        localStorage.setItem(id, valToCheck);
        localStorage.setItem(cls, color);
        return;
    } 
    
        document.getElementById("readunread3").value = valToCheck;
        document.getElementsByClassName("read3").value = color;
        localStorage.setItem("readunread3", valToCheck);
        localStorage.setItem("read3", color);
}

//works for if
readunread("readunread3","read3","Mark as Unread","White",true);

//works for else
readunread("readunread3","read3","Mark as Unread","Grey",false);
```